# Как убрать угловатость спрайта?

Tags: unity3d

При помещении из Blender в Unity у модели образуются углы, помогите это исправить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем тебе Блендер для спрайта в целом?

Answer (score 0):

Для отображения спрайтов не нужна модель. Используйте готовый [Sprite2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html). Если у вас объект состоит из нескольких деталей, то делайте их встроенными спрайтами с прозрачностьюИ анимацию в юнити проще делать будет.